# Copy the current UIMA CAS object

Tags: java, uima

I'm working on a project which uses [Apache UIMA](https://uima.apache.org/) framework to annotate documents. Since I have to pass all the documents once and process them in one for-lopp, so I have to temporarily store (copy) the current CAS object for the current document so as to avoid being messed up by following FSs and heap values.

So as is followed, I used CasCopier to firstly copy the current CAS and display that before processing the next document.

```
 1.  public class DocumentAnalysis {
 2.    public DocumentAnalysis(CAS cas) {
 3.        this.cas = cas;
 4.    }
 5.     
 6.    public processDocuments(Document documents) {
 7.        for(Document document: documents) {
 8.            // process each document, after this method, the cas has all values
 9.            processSingleDoc(document);
10.
11.            // create a new CAS as the destination of copy
12.            CAS localCas = CASFactory.createCas().getCas();
13. 
14.            // copy the current CAS to the new CAS
15.            CASCopier.copyCas(this.cas, localCas, true);  
16.        }
17.    }
18.
19.    public processSingleDoc(Document document) {
20.        // the logic for processing
21.        // implement UIMA process() method
22.        ......
23.    }
24.
25.    CAS cas;
26.  }
```

However, the problem is that it threw a NullPointerException at line 12 and I figured that the getCAS() method requires the indexRepository variable and the localCas I created doesn't have that value, which means that the creation of new CAS might be incorrect.

I've searched online and haven't found out any solutions yet. So does anyone know how I can copy the current CAS to a newly created CAS?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Where is `this.cas` instantiated? From this code sample, it is null, and thus the NPE.

Comment: @rmlan: Hi, it's my fault that I forgot to provide the constructor of this class. I've edited my post.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @rmlan, sorry but the code I provided is just mimic. And due to it's from my work, I cannot provide the stack trace which will disclose some private source code...

Comment: @D.Q. without more info it is difficult to help you. maybe remove part of the stacktrace that is confidential, and post the rest...

Comment: @D.Q. Did you find your answer?